# How to extract two values from each classes to put it in the testing set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

So I have got a dataset with 120 rows and 124 columns. The dependent column is the string name of people. There are altogether 20 different names. I would like to extract two rows from each classes(so extracting two rows with the same name for each classes) so that I can create a testing set with it.Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The best practice to create test data is use the function train_test_split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to do that:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,stratify =y)
```

Here,

> **X** = Dataframe with all independent variables.
>
> **y** = Series with dependent variable.
>
> **test_size** = The percentage you want as test size ,here 20%.
>
> **stratify** = Equal distribution of all category, in your case its name of 20 people.